# Polymer 1.0 Conditional dom-repeat issue

Tags: dom, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a custom element like this:

```html
<dom-module id="customer-location">
    <template>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{customers}}" filter="isCustomerFound" observe="cuname item.cuname">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{item.branches}}">
          ...
          ...
        </template>
      </template>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

This element has a property `cname` the value of which is set from `index.html`

```html
<customer-location cname="{{params.name}}"></customer-location>
```

The above value is transferred fine into `customer-location` element. I can print it like `<p id="maxp">{{cname}}</p>`.

Now, inside `<script>...</script>` I am trying to access the property `cname` using a function:

```html
<script>
  (function () {
      Polymer({
          // define element prototype here
          is: 'customer-location',
          properties: {
              latlngcombo: { type: String },
              cname: { type: String }
          },
              
          isCustomerFound: function (item) {
              var dm = this.$$("#maxp").innerHTML;  
              return item.cuname == dm;
          },

          ready: function () {
              this.customers = [
                  { "cuname": "msi", "name": "Microsoft India", "addr": "2, Strand Road", "addr2": "Kolkata, IN", "phone": "332.245.9910", "lat": "22.589091", "lng": "88.352359", "branches": [
                      { "branch": "Hyderabad", "email": "hydho@cyfoxpapers.com", "phone": "1582012244", "address": "69/A, Twisted Road, Banjara Hills, Hyderabad: 600001", "code": "CPHYD" }
                      ]
                  },
                  { "cuname": "googindia", "name": "Google India Inc.", "addr": "6/B, Pragati Apartment", "addr2": "Pitampura, New Delhi, IN", "phone": "493.050.2010", "lat": "28.61598", "lng": "77.244382" },
                  { "cuname": "gabonint", "name": "Gabon Internationl", "addr": "187 Kabi Kirandhan Road", "addr2": "Bhadrakali, IN", "phone": "983.193.3166", "lat": "22.665979", "lng": "88.348134" },
                  { "cuname": "itg", "name": "India Tour Guides", "addr": "115/5 Palash Sarani", "addr2": "Amritsar, India", "phone": "943.390.9166", "lat": "31.604877", "lng": "74.572276" },
                  { "cuname": "creatad", "name": "Creative Ad Agency", "addr": "25 BPMB Saranai", "addr2": "McLeodganj, Dharamsala. IN", "phone": "943.390.9166", "lat": "32.232596", "lng": "76.324327" }
                ];
              }
          });
      })();
</script>
```

The function `isCustomerFound` is intended to check whether current `cname` value matches with the `item.cuname` at the outer `dom-repeat` loop.

But I am never getting the value from `var mm = this.$$("#maxp").innerHTML;`

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. In another similar element `this.$$("#maxp").innerHTML` is getting the value fine!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a result of the `cname` attribute being bound outside of the scope of the element.  What's happening is that first the `<customer-location>` element is created and stamped onto the DOM, going through `ready`, `attached`, etc. THEN it receives the new value of `cname` as it is passed in via its parent's bindings.

The `dom-repeat` therefore first executes the `isCustomerFound` filter using an `undefined` value for `cname`, but does not know to re-parse the data after `cname` is updated.  Unfortunately because `cname` is not a property of the `items` collection it can't be put into `observe`, so you will have to observe the property externally and manually-retrigger the `dom-repeat` filtering.

```
<dom-module id="customer-location">
    <template>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{customers}}" id="customerList" filter="isCustomerFound" observe="cuname item.cuname">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{item.branches}}">
          ...
          ...
        </template>
      </template>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  (function () {
      Polymer({
          is: 'customer-location',

          properties: {
              latlngcombo: String,
              cname: String
          },

          observers: [
              '_updateCname(cname)'
          ],

          _updateCname: function(cname) {
              this.$.customerList.render();
          },

          isCustomerFound: function (item) {
              return item.cuname == this.cname;
          },

          ready: function () {
              this.customers = [
                  ...
              ];
          }
      });
  })();
</script>
```